# how can I parse "30.0" or "30.00" to Integer?

Tags: java

I using:

```
String str="300.0";
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(str));
```

return an exception:

***Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "300.0"***

How can I parse this String to int?

thanks for help :)

Comment: Why? Data formatted as 30.0 or 30.00 clearly *isn't* an integer at all, it is a real number.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's how you do it:

```
String str = "300.0";
System.out.println((int) Double.parseDouble(str));
```

The reason you got a `NumberFormatException` is simply that the string ("300.00", which is a floating point number) could not be parsed as an integer.

---

It may be worth mentioning, that this solution prints `300` even for input `"300.99"`. **To get a proper rounding**, you could do

```
System.out.println(Math.round(Double.parseDouble("300.99")));  // prints 301
```

Answer (score 3):

I am amazed no one has mentioned [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

It's really the best way to convert string of decimal's to int. 

Josuha Bloch suggest using this method in one of his puzzlers.

Here is the example run on [Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/cxss8)

```
class Test {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        java.math.BigDecimal v1 = new java.math.BigDecimal("30.0");
        java.math.BigDecimal v2 = new java.math.BigDecimal("30.00");            
      System.out.println("V1: " + v1.intValue() + " V2: " + v2.intValue());
    } catch(NumberFormatException npe) {
      System.err.println("Wrong format on number");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, which one do you think [comes closest to the correct answer](http://ideone.com/hzVi7)?

Comment: @aioobe: Nice catch. Maybe that was what the puzzle was all about. I just recalled it from my head :-)

Comment: I've actually filed [a bug report](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7000825) related to this very behaviour. You can vote for it if you agree that it's confusing ;)

Comment: I would recommend to use `intValueExact` if you want to be sure that the parsed string has no fractional part.

Comment: @Jörn Horstmann: Except I get a `java.lang.ArithmeticException: Overflow at java.math.BigDecimal.intValueExact(BigDecimal.java:3031)` when I try that

Comment: @aioobe: One thing I noted. It's true when you say `comes closest`. Because Instead of 2147483648 yours prints 2147483647, which is still wrong.

Comment: @aioobe: Ok, some more info. I just watched the parleys.com puzzlers talk by Joshua Bloch, and they say that you should use the constructor that takes the string in BigDecimal

Answer (score 2):

You should parse it to `double` first and then cast it to `int`:

```
String str="300.0";
System.out.println((int)(Double.parseDouble(str)));
```

You need to catch `NumberFormatException`s though.

Edit: thanks to Joachim Sauer for the correction.

Comment: *Almost* correct, he should parse to `double` and then cast to `int`. A `Double` can't be cast to an `Integer`.

Comment: no you don't need to catch the `NumberFormatException` as 1) "300.0" will parse just fine, 2) it is not a checked exception.

Comment: @aioobe: I made the assumption that the string wouldn't be "300.0" all the time, and could potentially contain an invalid value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Double.parseDouble()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) method to first cast it to `double` and afterwards cast the `double` to int by putting `(int)` in front of it. You then get the following code:

```
String str="300.0";
System.out.println((int)Double.parseDouble(str));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Integer.parseInt()` **has** to take a string that's an integer (i.e. no decimal points, even if the number is equivalent to an integer. The exception you're getting there is essentially saying "you've told me this number is an integer, but this string isn't in a valid format for an integer!"

If the number contains a decimal component, then you'll need to use `Double.parseDouble()`, which will return a double primitive. However, since you're not interested in the decimal component you can safely drop it by just casting the double to an int:

```
int num = (int)Double.parseDouble(str);
```

Note however that this will just drop the decimal component, it won't round the number up at all. So casting 1.2, 1.8 or 1.999999 to an int would all give you 1. If you want to round the number that comes back then use [Math.round()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) instead of just casting to an int.